# Reiniciar classe

Tags: android

Tenho que verificar a consistência de alguns campos no meu aplicativo, mas não consigo fazer com que o processo pare para que o usuário digite a informação correta. Do jeito que coloquei, a mensagem de erro é apresentada mas o processamento continua, veja os comandos baixo. O que devo fazer?

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (rendim.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        rendim.setError("Preencha o salário");
        rendim.requestFocus();
        imm.showSoftInput(rendim, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
    else
    {
        objVal_or = new Val_or();
        rendimento = objVal_or.va_lor(rendim.getText().toString());
        if (rendimento <= 0)
        {
            rendim.setError("Salário zerado");
            rendim.requestFocus();
            imm.showSoftInput(rendim, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Em qual situação o processo continua, quando deveria parar? Não entendi o que realmente esta acontecendo. Se não é preenchido o campo `rendim` ficar vazio e aparece a mensagem de `Preencha o salário` Se o `rendim` for preenchido e for `<=0`aparece `Salário zerado`

Comment: Resolvi, faltava o comando return no final do bloco do IF, mudei para uma forma mais simples:

if (rendim.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            rendim.setError("Preencha o salário");
            rendim.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            objVal_or = new Val_or();
            rendimento = objVal_or.va_lor(rendim.getText().toString());
            if (rendimento <= 0)
            {
                rendim.setError("Salário zerado");
                rendim.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
        }